# NANT 0.92 SDK 7 not found

Tags: nant

Environment:

Windows 2008 R2 64Bit SDK installed at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1**

Framework installed at **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319**

Trying to run Nant to compile some .NET 4 classes and we are getting
the following message.

```
The SDK for the 'net-4.0' framework is not available or not configured.:

            NAnt.Core.BuildException: The SDK for the 'net-4.0'
framework is not available or not configured.
               at NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExternalProgramBase.DetermineFilePath()
               at NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExternalProgramBase.get_ProgramFileName()
               at
NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExternalProgramBase.PrepareProcess(Process process)
               at NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExternalProgramBase.StartProcess()
               at NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExternalProgramBase.ExecuteTask()
               at NAnt.Core.Task.Execute()
               at NAnt.Core.Target.Execute()
               at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute(String targetName, Boolean
forceDependencies)
               at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute()
               at NAnt.Core.Project.Run()
```

In looking at the NANt.exe.config it would appear that it looks to the
registry to find the applicable path for the SDK.

```
<project>
 <readregistry
     property="installRoot"
      key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\InstallRoot"
      hive="LocalMachine" />
 <locatesdk property="sdkInstallRoot"
 minwinsdkver="v7.0A" minnetfxver="4.0" maxnetfxver="4.0.99999"
 failonerror="false" />
</project>
```

The key does not exist in the registry nor does our SDK version match the minwinsdkver="v7.0A"

Anyone run into this issue and found a valid work-around?

Comment: If the registry keys aren't there, isn't that more of an SDK installation issue rather than NAnt?

Comment: On a 64 bit machine, my 7.1 SDK is installed at: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1 (not at Program Files (x86)) maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to add the key to the registry.

For myself the registry entry was slightly different: at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework set sdkInstallRootv2.0=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A.

After this Nant compiled fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue yesterday. Another workaround is to mark the NAnt executable as 32 bit.

1. Open a Developer Command Prompt
2. Change to the directory that contains your NAnt executable.
3. Run the following command: *corflags NAnt.exe /32Bit+*